# Up to date list of exchanges that have been hacked?

Tags: exchanges

One key detail I'd like to consider when reviewing which exchange to do trading on, is how often, and recently have they been hacked?

I can see lots of random posts about this of course for various exchanges, but would love to find a chart that lists this type of information, with up to date information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few sources I found but obviously are not completely up to date or don't have the full history, as you probably found. Some great sources for the overall history of Bitcoin and hacks are:

1. [historyofbitcoin.org](http://historyofbitcoin.org)
2. [fastcompany.com](https://www.fastcompany.com/40505199/bitcoin-heist-adds-77-million-to-hacked-hauls-of-15-billion)
3. [theguardian.com](https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2014/mar/18/history-of-bitcoin-hacks-alternative-currency)

Now, for the moment we've all been waiting for.... [This source (bravenewcoin.com)](https://bravenewcoin.com/news/mtgox-btc-e-and-the-missing-coins-a-living-timeline-of-the-greatest-cyber-crime-ever/) I believe gives the best overview and history of all the hacks and even additional information, from 2007 to 2017.

Keep in mind the I posted the other sources above because it's always good to fact check, and each source has some different information.

And sadly, I do not believe that they have a chart or document listing who, when, and how much Bitcoin as hacked from exchanges... yet. I'd also ask around on [bitcointalk.org](https://bitcointalk.org), someone on there might have one or etc.

Happy Bitcoining